# DAO layer testing strategy with JUnit and Spring

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit, dao

I'm trying to devise an optimal strategy to unit-test DAO layer of my Spring app.
Many existing approaches like in-memory DB usage, etc (posts: 12289800, 12390813, 9940010, 12801926). do not appeal to me.

So, here is a straightforward way that occurs to me:

1. Create Spring test-context.xml and put there all the data needed for testing all the DAO classes;
2. For each test class create a template method to test CRUD operations and all 'select' operations;
3. Before testing, insert all needed data from test-context.xml to your real DB. We may need also some dependencies (references), so insert them as well, let's say in @Before method.
4. After all CRUD operations, delete all dependencies (references) from DB, let's say in @After method.

If we have a lot of dependencies, this may become a terribly expensive and laborious approach. Also we have only one @Test method (template method, to ensure the order of operations: create, read... etc.) - so one test per test class.

So, I need an advice whether this strategy is viable? What similar did you do to test your DAOs?

Comment: Which IDE are you using it depends , if you want to use STS IDE then put your dependencies in pom.xml which will maintain and help you with update   dependencies . The path you are following it is necessary so your going in a right way. The testing is necessary before you put your code in production.so test it by Junit .

Comment: By dependencies I mean other entities of the DB connected to a given table in DB)) In other words references to other tables. We cannot depend on existing ones, so need to insert it to test properly.

Comment: Food for thought: http://dbsetup.ninja-squad.com/user-guide.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all, I ended up with this strategy for testing classes responsible for interacting with the database in Spring-based app. Key thoughts:

1. Use an in-memory DB (H2 is OK), a separate Spring profile with test data source and settings.
2. Database is set up at the beginning of the entire test process from the schema.sql scripts. So we need to have the sql sources to rebuild the test database. Possibly it comes from DBA or yourself if you are designing the database on your own. Tools like **liquibase or flyway** are if you work with the database in a large team, where everybody needs the actual state of the database by applying incremental scripts. In this way the results setup script in managed by the tool.
3. Obviously each test case will require its own set of data to be initialized before executing the test. We do it by making sample.sql/clear_sample.sql scripts (a pair for each test case) to insert and delete data before and after each case. For this we can use either spring's annotations: [@Sql](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/jdbc/Sql.html) or [ScriptUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/init/ScriptUtils.html)
4. To help designing tests we can inject EntityManager for example for retrieving inserted with the help of sql scripts.
5. Basic JUnit asserts are used to compare.

Thus, we have no additional software layer, like DbUnit or anything and write isolated and maintainable unit-tests.
The unavoidable downside is that when a more or less significant change comes to the DB we need to rewrite the whole test, or even several.